# Why can't I reassign a variable that was formerly allocated on the stack in C++ (copy assignment operator of 'Frame' is implicitly deleted)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have the following setup:

```
struct Frame {
    Frame(vector<Region> regions_)
        : regions(regions_){}
    const vector<Region> regions;
};
```

Now, at a different part in my code I want to create a `vector<Frame>` and created the following `for` loop:

```
vector<Frame> shot;
Frame currentFrame = generateRandomFrame();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    shot.push_back(currentFrame);
    currentFrame = generateNextFrame(currentFrame); // this line gives the error
}
```

where `generateNextFrame`has the following signature: 
`Frame FrameGenerator::generateNextFrame(Frame previousFrame)`

Now, this code won't compile and give me the following error:

```
copy assignment operator of 'Frame' is implicitly 
deleted because field 'regions' has no copy assignment 
operator const vector<Region> regions;
```

Now, I don't fully understand this error message. I strongly assume that it's related to the fact that `currentFrame` is allocated on the *stack* and not on the *heap*, and thus I can't just reassign the variable. Being a novice to C++ however, I am not familiar with how to handle these kinds of situations. Should I use pointers here instead and try to allocate `currentFrame` on the heap?

To be clear, my goal is to generate a series of `frames` (that depend on some previous frame). Can anyone point me into the right direction here?

**Update:**
Thanks a lot for all the hints in the comments, I now understand that the issue comes from the fact that I declare `regions` as `const`. I rewrote the code to use pointers instead of heap variables, it now looks like this:

```
vector<Frame> shot;
Frame currentFrame = generateRandomFrame();
Frame *currentFramePtr = &currentFrame; // the first frame in the shot is random
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    shot.push_back(*currentFramePtr);
    Frame tmpFrame = generateNextFrame(*currentFramePtr);
    currentFramePtr = &tmpFrame; 
}
```

This code does compile now, however it still doesn't do what I want. According to my understanding it should now work, because I am storing the `currentFrame` in a pointer, so I can easily override it with new objects that I create. But it seems that there still is a bug, the frame generation doesn't work as expected (that is any new frame is generated with 0 regions while the number of regions should be identical to the previous frame). Can anyone see what's wrong with this updated version of my code?

Comment: You can't change something that's `const`, so you can't change `currentFrame.regions`.

Comment: ah ok! I know in C++ it's common to override operators. would it be an option to override the "copy" operator of `Frame`? does that make sense?

Comment: It's `operator =` that you're calling here. `currentFrame = ...;` calls `currentFrame.operator=(...);`

Comment: If you try to write your own `operator=`, you should see why it's impossible, and therefore why the compiler is complaining that it can't automatically generate one.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to assign to something with a const data member, because you'd expect assignment would change the member.

Comment: Being more explicit: change `const vector<Region> regions;` to `vector<Region> regions;`.

Comment: all right! thanks a lot for the hints everyone! I would like to keep my `regions` as`const`, so what are the options then? is it possible to circumvent this situation using pointers instead of stack variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `struct` declares a `const` member, which forces compiler to implicitly delete default copy assignment operator due to the fact that `const` member doesn't have copy assignment operator.

The code below replaces the bits you omitted from the sample and shows how to generate a bunch of `Frame *`s instead of `Frame`s. Basically, it's a workaround for your compilation issue, but it may not suit your specific need if your code REQUIRES stack usage or you'd have to refactor too much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Region{};

struct Frame {
    Frame(std::vector<Region> regions_)
    : regions(regions_){}
    const std::vector<Region> regions;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::vector<Frame *> shot;
    Frame * currentFrame = new Frame((std::vector<Region>()));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        shot.push_back(currentFrame);
        currentFrame = new Frame(std::vector<Region>());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also please note:
[how to use const_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554841/how-to-use-const-cast) - `const_cast` won't work for you and will cause UB. Just in case ;)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! do you maybe have an advice how I can reach my goal without declaring `regions` as non-`const`?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely insist on keeping `regions` const, and having "assignment", you can destroy the existing `Frame` and create a new one in place.

```
std::vector<Frame> shot;
Frame currentFrame = generateRandomFrame();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    shot.push_back(currentFrame);
    currentFrame.~Frame();
    new (&currentFrame) Frame(generateNextFrame(shot.back()));
}
```

However an even easier way would be to not reassign anything

```
std::vector<Frame> shot;
shot.push_back(generateRandomFrame());
for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    shot.push_back(generateNextFrame(shot.back()));
}
```