# casting away the constness using const_cast

Tags: c++, const-char

No. This question in NOT duplicate of 
[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

The question asked here is no ways similar to the link described as duplicate.

**First question :** 
I am using const_cast below for two cases. one of it works. the other doesn't.

**1.** **int* const**     //Works.

In this syntax the address to which the variable would point to cannot be changed. So i used const_cast as below and it works:

```
`
int j=3;
int *k=&j;
int *m=&j;
int* const i=k; 
const_cast<int*>(i)=m; //OK: since i=m would not work so cast is necessary`
```

**2.** **const int***  //Doesn't work.

The address being pointed to can be changed however the value cannot be changed(though can be changed by making the variable point to different address). The const_cast i am using doesn't seem to work here:

```
`
int j=9;
int *k=&j;
const int* i1=0;
i1=k; //OK
//*i1=10;//ERROR.`
```

So i tried to typecast as below through various ways but nothing works:

```
const_cast<int*>(i1)=10;
const_cast<int*>(*i1)=l;
*i1=const_cast<int>(l);
*i1=const_cast<int*>(10);
```

**Second question:**
Are all the casts available only for pointers and references?
Is the following example not valid where no pointer or reference is in picture?

```
const int a=9;
int b=4;
const_cast<int>(a)=b; //cannot convert from 'int' to 'int'. why is compiler
                      //trying to convert from int to int anyways or fails         
                      //when both the types are same.
```

Comment: You missed one variation: `*const_cast<int*>(i1) = 10;`

Comment: You probably want `const_cast<int&>(*i1)=10;` for `2`

Comment: and `const_cast<int*>(i)=m;` is wrong as well, you probably meant `const_cast<int*&>(i)=m;`

Comment: @Piotr : thanks it works. But could you please explain why it works. the type to which we are casting should match with the RHS. How does int& match with the value 10?

Comment: @piotr: No, i meant const_cast<int*>(i)=m;   and not const_cast<int*&>.(i)=m.  where int *m=&j;

Comment: @anurag86 `const_cast<int*>(i)=m;` won't compile, expression `const_cast<int*>` has a prvalue value-category, so it can't be assigned to

Comment: @piotr: trust me it works on vs2008. I have cross checked it just now and also tried printing *i before and after the cast. <int*&> works too.

Comment: @anurag86, don't print just `*i`. Print `i` also. To see whether `i` itself is changing. Also, perhaps initialize `i` with NULL so that you really can see if it is being changed to `m`.

Comment: @Aaron : *i and i change "After" the cast.  If i initialize i to NULL and then cast directly to assign to m then the code compiles but crashes during execution.

Comment: @anurag86 *"then the code compiles but crashes during execution."* a crash is a great example of UB

Comment: @piotr: Actually it crashes in both the following cases irrespective i use    const_cast<int*&>(i)=m;  or const_cast<int*>(i)=m;       . though i couldnt still understand the meaning of <int*&>(i)=m

Comment: @anurag86 `&` denotes you want a modifiable reference to the original expression, otherwise `static_cast` would create a new temporary object that can't be assigned to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const_cast` is applied to *expressions*, not objects, and itself is an *expression* as well:

§ 5.2.11 [expr.const.cast]/p1:

> The result of the expression `const_cast<T>(v)` is of type `T`. If `T` is an lvalue reference to object type, the
>   result is an lvalue; if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue; otherwise, the result
>   is a prvalue and the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard
>   conversions are performed on the expression `v`

1. `const_cast<int*>(i)=m;`

This call is invalid, because the left side of the assignment has a *prvalue* value-category, and an `int*` prvalue doesn't support an assignment. The correct syntax would be `const_cast<int*&>(i)=m;`, but since `i` in your example was declared `const`, it would invoke undefined behavior <sup>†</sup>.

2. `const_cast<int*>(*i1)=l;`

Dereferencing a pointer of type `int*` creates an expression of an lvalue value-category, and because the cast expression is on the left side of the assignment, it should be a cast to an lvalue reference type, namely `const_cast<int&>(*i1)=10;` (provided that whatever `i1` points to was not declared `const`).

3. `const_cast<int>(a)=b;`

The `const_cast<int>(a)` part itself is valid, in particular you can apply a const_cast to an expression representing an object which is not of a pointer type neither of a reference type. But since it's on the left side of the assigment it won't compile. And even if you change it to `const_cast<int&>(a)=b;` it will trigger undefined behavior, because `a` is declared `const` <sup>†</sup>.

---

<sup>†</sup> § 7.1.6.1 [dcl.type.cv]/p4:

> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const
>   object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

**First answer**: In your example you are trying to force compiler to do something which can be interpreted like this

```
const_cast<int*>(i1)=10; //int* = int: assign address to pointer
const_cast<int*>(*i1)=l; //const_cast<int*>(int): cast the value under pointer to pointer
*i1=const_cast<int>(l); //const_casting from const values is forbidden
*i1=const_cast<int*>(10); //10 is an rvalue
```

What you really want to do here is to dereference a pointer that is non-const anymore. That's why you need to do it like this:

```
int j = 9;
int *k = &j;
const int* i1 = 0;
i1 = k;
*(const_cast<int*>(i1)) = 10;
```

which is equivalent to

```
int j = 9;
int *k = &j;
const int* i1 = 0;
i1 = k;
int* temp = const_cast<int*>(i1); //you get rid of 'const'...
*temp = 10; //...and now you assign value as you wanted to - this operation became available
```

---

**Second answer**: It is forbidden to `const_cast` const values as it leads to undefined behavior. You are only allowed to remove constness from pointers or references that points to something that is not really `const` in the end and only the pointer disallows you to modify its value.

This issue is awesomely described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554841/how-to-use-const-cast) answer.

Comment: Perfectly explained. Thanks a lot. :)