# C++ decltype(auto) of const reference return type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

This is the test program I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
decltype(auto) foo(T& arg)
{
    return arg;
}

int main()
{
    const int x = 10;
    int & y = const_cast<int&>(foo(x));
    y = 20;
    cout << "x: " << &x << " " << x << endl;
    cout << "y: " << &y << " " << y << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp  && ./a.out
x: 0x7ffee31f4a6c 10
y: 0x7ffee31f4a6c 20
```

Why was the value of `x` not changed even though `foo` returned a `const int&` to which it was `const_cast`'ed to `int&`?

Because from the output it seems like the two addresses of `x` and `y` are the same.

Comment: Also possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3593687/1896169