# What does (X* nptr = new (ptr) X {} ) mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

What does (ptr) stands for and why does it change the data stored in ptr?

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    int const b;
};
    
X* ptr = new X{ 1, 2 };
X* nptr = new (ptr) X{ 3, 4 };
```

And for some reason it doesn't run in any godbolt's compilers but does in visual studio

Comment: Seems like the author of this code was trying to reinvent the assignment-operator in the most dangerous way possible (short of `memcpy()`, anyway :) )

Comment: Read about [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222578/12002570) and also refer to [Two different values at the same memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593687/two-different-values-at-the-same-memory-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires `#include <new>` to work. It is an overloaded `new` operator which calls the constructor without allocating new memory. Instead, the new struct is constructed to memory pointed by `ptr` and the old data is thus overwritten. See [that](https://cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) for reference.